# TypeError with 'infer_datetime_format'

Tags: python, pandas

When i read excel file.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Online Retail.xlsx',
                   dtype={'CustomerID': str,
                          'InvoiceID': str},
                   parse_dates=['InvoiceDate'], 
                   infer_datetime_format=True)

df.head()
```

I got this error, anyone help this please.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-83803a31652e> in <module>()
      3                           'InvoiceID': str},
      4                    parse_dates=['InvoiceDate'],
----> 5                    infer_datetime_format=True)
      6 
      7 df.head()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'infer_datetime_format'
```

PS. I worked on google colabs.

Comment: Because [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has no keyword argument `infer_datetime_format`. Side note, don't confuse Excel and CSV files.

Comment: Big thanks @BigBen, So i need to convert Excel into CSV right?

Comment: You need to drop the `infer_datetime_format=True`.